# PHP Codeigniter, assigning property value and accesing it

Tags: php, codeigniter, properties

I am trying to assign a value to a property from one function, and access it in another function. I thought that this should be as simple as that. Unfortunately I can't seem to handle this simple task.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class Form_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $current_user;
    public $pi = 3.14;

    function index() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login_form');
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Admin_Users_Model');
            $is_logged_in = $this->Admin_Users_Model->login();

            if ($is_logged_in) {
                $this->load->view('admin_panel/panel');
                $this->load->view('admin_panel/account_verification_status_form');
            } else {
                $this->load->view('login_form');
            }
        }
    }

    function account_verification() {

        $this->load->model('User_Id_Model');
        $data['user_data'] = $this->User_Id_Model->get_user_credentials();

        $this->current_user = $data['user_data'];

        foreach ($this->current_user as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }

        $this->load->view('admin_panel/panel');
        $this->load->view('admin_panel/account_verification_status_form');
        $this->load->view('admin_panel/account_verification_name_form', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin_panel/account_verification_status', $data);
    }

    function name_verification() {

        $selected_value = $this->input->post('verify-name');

        echo count($this->current_user) . '<br />';

        echo $this->current_user;
        echo $this->pi;
      $this->account_verification();
    }

    private function _write_to_database($user_data) {
        $this->load->model('User_Id_Model');
        $this->User_Id_Model->write_to_database($user_data);
    }

}
?>
```

When I call `account_verification()`, `$current_user` is assigned a value, and I am able to print it. After that I am calling `name_verification()`, but `$current_user` has no value.
If you know what is going on here, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all after looking at your code

1) if you are calling name_varification from url than you are not assigning any value to the global varibale ie

```
    $this->current_user.
```

2) if you are calling account_varification from url than you have assigne data to golbal variable

```
 $this->current_user
```

and you are not calling name_varification from within account_varification so again it means you are calling it from url so ofcourse it will loose its value so proper code is either call first name_varificaton and assign it following data.

```
   $this->load->model('User_Id_Model');
   $data['user_data'] = $this->User_Id_Model->get_user_credentials();
   $this->current_user = $data['user_data'];
```

after that call $this->account_verification like just you are calling than both functions will have values

i hope you understand.
Regards
Imran Qasim

Comment: I do not know what do you mean. Please elaborate.
To clarify - I have a view with a form. The form calls account_verification()
account_verification() adds one more view, which loads another form.
When the second form is submitted it calls name_verification().
In account_verification() I get some user credentials:
$data['user_data'] = $this->User_Id_Model->get_user_credentials();
What I am trying to do is pass that credentials to second method, so I can update that user in the DB with values recieved from the second form.

Comment: if there are two forms it means you are calling both functions via url so when u call name_varification function than global variable current_user doesn't retain its value. thats what i mean, if you want to retain those value than u need to use session to reatins the value after submitting first form and that get those value from session when u call 2nd method name_varification this will solve your problem.

Comment: You are actually right. Adding it to the session makes it possible to pass it to the next function... All that is left for me is to figure out what to do from now on :X

Comment: How do I select your post as answer?

Comment: just click the up arrow key which is on left over 0